# Mots masculins se terminant en -AIN dont le féminin est en -INE

Tags: genre, étymologie

Le mot « sacristain » admet les féminins « sacristaine » et « sacristine ». Le mot « génovéfain » n'admet que le féminin « génovéfine ». Mes deux questions sont :

1. Existe-t-il d'autres mots masculins se terminant en -AIN et admettant un féminin en -INE ?
2. D'où vient cette féminisation particulière ? L'origine est-elle cléricale ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il y a [*copain*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/copain).

Dans ces deux cas (les sources que je peux consulter donnent *génofévaine* comme féminin de *génofévain*), la formation du féminin est plus tardive que celle du masculin s'il faut en croire Grevisse (Bon usage, 14e éd, §495). Les locuteurs ont vraisemblablement présumé que le masculin était en -in. *Sacristaine* est d'ailleurs attesté (notamment comme féminin de l'adjectif).

Answer (score 1):

Suite au commentaire, je n'ai trouvé que des 'faux amis' :

- *[Alain](http://www.prenoms.com/v2/services-prenom/signification-prenom.asp)* : Vient du latin "Alanus" Nom d'une peuplade près de la mer Noire. Se fête le 9 septembre. Au féminin *Alaine* .
- *[Aline](http://www.prenoms.com/v2/services-prenom/signification-prenom.asp)* :  Diminutif d'Adeline et dérivé d'Adèle. Vient du germain "Ada " Signifie: "Noble" Se fête le 20 octobre

et découvert le mot *clarain* dans le *[Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr)* :

- *clarain* : Un des constituants pétrographiques de la houille, d'apparence homogène et brillante, à cassure fibreuse.
- *clarine* : Clochette des animaux à l'alpage.

autre faux ami (définition du petit Robert) :

- *andain* : Ligne de foin séché, que l'on forme après le fanage et avant le ramassage.
- *andine* : (nom ou adjectif au féminin) des Andes.

Comment: *Andain* est uniquement un [nom masculin](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andain_%28homonymie%29), pas un adjectif. L'adjectif est *andin* et est régulier. *Aline* n'est pas habituellement considéré comme le féminin "normal" d'*Alain*. Je crois que la plupart des gens considérerait qu'il s'agit d'une substitution du suffixe du genre qu'on a avec *Christian→Christiane, Christine, Christelle* etc.

Comment: @Circeus merci ; j'étais persuadé qu'*Aline* était la mode féminine d'*Alain*, d'autant plus que je ne connait pas d'*Alaine* (ni mon correcteur de texte), j'aurais dû vérifier pour *andain/andine*